# Use plm in R with variable names with spaces

Tags: r, plm

I am trying to run a fixed effect model on a data with the variables `Deaths` and `Mean income` over time `year` and `region`. The problem is that the package I use, `plm` does not support variable names with spaces like `Mean income`. That is, the income variable is not found if I run the regression like below. (error message: `object 'Mean income' not found`)

```
plm(formula = Deaths ~ `Mean income`, data=RegressionDataRegion, index=c("region"), model="within")
```

I know that I can rename the variables in the data panel, but I am very reluctant to do so. Is there any way to use `plm` with spaces in the variable name?

Comment: You should really stick to the naming standards to save you a lot of cumulative trouble. It's actually very easy to rename your variables, just do `names(RegressionDataRegion) <- make.names(names(RegressionDataRegion))`. Also read `?make.names`.

Comment: Thanks, that is a really nice hint! It still is a bit sad that one cannot use spaces for column names.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is to use "." to replace the spaces, even without have to change the column names like below:

```
plm(formula = Deaths ~ `Mean.income`, data=RegressionDataRegion, index=c("region"), model="within")
```